# how to detect touch which appear on the location greater than resolution of device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I'm looking for help. I'm trying to make some puzzle game and I have thin scrollable layer at the bottom of my main layer which contains some puzzle shapes. I can scroll the layer and see every shape but shapes were positioned manually in code on the scrollable layer and the problem is, if I try to detect if I touched on sprite, which position is greater than 1024(in first iPad) it doesn't work. it doesn't work because touch can have position inside 1024X768 and the position of shape is for example 1500x100. to make it clearer, shapes are sprites and i try to detect them using CGRectContainsPoints method. Is there any other way to make it or have you any ideas? thanks in advance :]

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is subclass your sprite, create a delegate for it and assign your main view/class as the delegate.

Implement the appropriate touch method, and send the message of what sprite was selected to your delegate (Main view or desired controller class).

With this every sprite has the same delegate, and sends a message to your controlling class as to what sprite has been selected and continue with desired functionality. No need for `CGRectContainsPoint` method.

This is cleaner, and more efficient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. I'm not going to pretend that I understand it completely :) because I would say I'm a beginner. Have you maybe a link to some blog or site which explains something similar to your idea? Thanks.

Comment: Found this tutorial which is pretty good, http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2011/04/12/simple-delegate-tutorial-for-ios-development/ .

Comment: I don't get it. I'm not sure how to start this "appropriate touch method". I'm not aware of any others method than CGRectContainsPoints and CGRectContainsRect to find out if I touched sprite so this is my main question, btw thanks for link.

Comment: You can utilize the `UITapGestureRecognizer` class to implement touch detection on your Sprites. Google it for examples.